# Empty POST on submit

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, post, configuration-files

I have a new CodeIgniter instalation and I want to create a login form. When I submit the page it collects no data in POST. This seems to be a server configuration issue rather than CodeIgniter, but I can't figure it out.

My view:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" action="/administrator/login/submit" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
...
</form>
```

Same behavior happens if I use full path in the action tag, I just tried it.

My controller

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view("administrator/login_view");
    }

    function submit()
    {
        $this->output->enable_profiler(); 
        //var_dump($_POST);
        var_dump($_REQUEST);

    }
}
```

Codeigniter is in /var/www/sub/

```
/var/www/sub$ ls
application  index.php  license.txt  skins  system  user_guide
```

My .htaccess in /var/www/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/index.php?/$1 [L]  
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /administrator/login/

<Files "index.php">
    AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

My apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I browse to the url (page loads correctly redirecting to IP/sub/index.php/administrator/login)

```
http://{SERVER_IP}/administrator/login/
```

Enter user/password and click submit. But then I don't get anything back, POST is empty.

Output of $_POST

```
array(0) { }
```

Output of $_REQUEST

```
array(1) { ["/administrator/login/submit"]=> string(0) "" }
```

I have a default setting for /var/www folder in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

For port 443 and 80 respectively.

**Not a CodeIgniter issue.**

I was able to prove this as I created /var/www/first.php

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>
    <form action="second.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" id="name"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Go"/>   
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and /var/www/second.php

```
<?php
    echo "<hr>Post: ";
    var_dump($_POST);

    echo "<hr>Get: ";
    var_dump($_GET);

    echo "<hr>Request: ";
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

And same thing happens, POST is empty

So here I am, having all these details but being unable to connect the dots. Please help

Comment: I removed the html subfolder and made canges in sites-available. I updated the post with the new info. Still same result, POST is empty

Comment: Where is this controller 'login' located , inside administrator folder. ?

Comment: yes. /var/www/sub/application/controllers/administrator/login.php. I renamed it to 'admin' to see if there is any change. Same result.

Comment: I also cleared completely the .htaccess file (commented everything using # for every line) and use the http://IP/sub/index.php/administrator/login to go to controller and then in the view I use the full path to post back (ended in /submit) and restarted apache but still same result.

Comment: I modified the post to prove this is not a CodeIgniter issue (see last part)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this.

```
action="<?php echo site_url('administrator/login/submit');?>"
```

Comment: that will just translate to 'administrator/login/submit' which I tried before. Nevertheless, I copy pasted your code in the view, just in case I missed something or a miracle happens. So the answer is no, still same result

Comment: Perhaps there must be something wrong with your routes then. Paste the code from your routes.php file

Comment: Check the latest example, where I believe I prove this is not CI related. But, as I am unsure I know what the issue is and you may be right, I will post the routes in CI. It is the default as it comes from CI2.2.0 as I haven't change anything:
`
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
`

Comment: Hmm. It seems to be something else than , if it's a server issue can't you just confirm it by testing for POST values outside of CI.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have those variables enabled. See [this configuration option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order).

Comment: I added the line "variables_order = "GCPS" in PHP.ini, restarted apache, I saw the update in PHPINFO but same result, still no values in POST